# When do the closed sets in a $KC$ space $X$ not necessarily coincide with the compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A topological space $( X,\tau)$ will be called a $C - C$ space iff the closed set inn $X$ coincide with the compact sets in $X$.

A topological space $( X,\tau)$ will be called a $KC$ space iff the compact subsets are closed.

So, $C - C$ space is $KC$.

**Is there example to show that $KC$ space does not imply $C-C$?**

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean $KC$ does not imply $C-C$. Consider the real numbers under the usual topology. Can you find a closed non-compact set?

In general, a space is $C-C$ if and only if it is compact $KC$. (Why?)

Comment: it`s answer is " when are compact and closed equivalent? " by " Norman Levine" Theorem 4

Comment: I knew from your previous question that you're reading Levine, but if you're reading that document and still asking this question, then you aren't understanding, yet. "Theorem 4" is *not* the answer to why. Theorem 4 just says that it's true. I'm asking you to think about why a $C-C$ space is both $KC$ and compact, and why a compact $KC$ space is $C-C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a $KC$ space, then every compact set in $X$ is closed, but that does not mean that every closed set in $X$ is compact. If $X$ is $KC$ but contains a closed set $F$ that is not compact, then clearly $X$ is not $C$-$C$.

You know that every Hausdorff space is $KC$, and you know that a space is always a closed subset of itself. Thus, a non-compact Hausdorff space is a $KC$ space that is not $C$-$C$, and you should be able to think of lots of non-compact Hausdorff spaces.

Perhaps you’re wondering whether there can be a *compact* example of a $KC$ space that is not $C$-$C$. It’s a fairly easy exercise to show that the answer is *no*. You may even have proved the following proposition at some point; if not, you should try now to do so.

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be any compact space, not necessarily $KC$, and let $K$ be a closed subset of $X$; then $K$ is compact.

Thus, in every compact space the closed sets are all compact. If in addition the space is $KC$, the compact sets are all closed, and the space is $C$-$C$, so every compact $KC$ space is $C$-$C$.

In the other direction it’s completely trivial that a $C$-$C$ space must be both compact and $KC$; why?